# Build hash with computed properties out of a service class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like help to finish a piece of code. I don't exactly how to explain what I need, so I will show you bit by bit.

I have this model:

```
class Metric < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: :post
  after_save: :analysis!

  # The table Metrics has the following columns:
  # adverb_count
  # adverb_density
  # sentiment
  # word_count
  # letter_count

  def analysis!
    res = MetricService.call post.body
    update! res
  end
end
```

Once a metric instance is saved, I need to call an external service that will return a hash containing properties that will help me computate the values `adverb_count`, `adverb_density`, `sentiment`, `word_count`, and finally `letter_count`. For that, I've created a `MetricService` class that encapsulates this logic:

```
class ApplicationService
  def self.call(*args, &block)
    new(*args, &block).call
  end
end

class MetricService < ApplicationService
  extend Memoist

  def initiaze(text)
    @text = text
  end

  # TODO: return the
  def call
    pre_analysis
    # =>
    #  Hash containing several props

    post_nalysis
    # =>
    #  Hash containing sereral props
  end

  private

  def pre_analysis
    client.pre_analysis @text
  end
  memoize :pre_analysis

  def post_analysis
    client.post_analysis pre_analysis['id']
  end

  def client
    SDK::Service.new ENV['API_KEY']
  end
  memoize :client
end
```

After the instantiation of this class, I call two methods of the `client`: `pre_analysis` and `post_analyis`, and with those two informations I can finally computate the values of properties `adverb_count, adverb_density, sentiment, word_count, and letter_count` and return it to the `Metric`. What I would like to do is create for each property a method:

```
class MetricService < ApplicationService

   # ...
   def adverb_count
     # use pre_analysis and post_analysis to computate this value here
   end

   def adverb_density
     # use pre_analysis and post_analysis to computate this value here
   end

   def sentiment
     # use pre_analysis and post_analysis to computate this value here
   end

   def word_count
     # use pre_analysis and post_analysis to computate this value here
   end

   def letter_count
     # use pre_analysis and post_analysis to computate this value here
   end
   # ...
end
```

And from the `call` method I just call them and return the hash.

From what I researched, services on ROR should only contain one public method, so I guess I should keep those properties private. Is this a correct assumption?

Is there a way to build the hash from `#call` without having to call each one of those methods individually? E.g:

```
def call
  {
    adverb_count: adverb_count
    # etc
  }
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metaprogramming like:

```
# the only public method
def call
  %w[adverb_count adverb_density sentiment word_count letter_count].each_with_object({}) do |method_name, result|
    result[method_name] = send(method_name)
  end
end

private

def adverb_count
  # use pre_analysis and post_analysis to computate this value here
end

def adverb_density
  # use pre_analysis and post_analysis to computate this value here
end

# and so on...
```

Comment: Oh awesome, that's what I was looking for.